# Cochrane Database of Systematic Reviews dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset that would contain [Cochrane Database of Systematic Reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochrane_Library). Ideally, with some structured format, e.g. separating each section of the systematic review, or with some organized references.

http://www.cochranelibrary.com/help/open-access-options-for-the-cochrane-library.html does mention

> Machine readability is one of the core components included in the guide. Contact Deborah Pentesco-Gilbert (dpentesc@wiley.com) to discuss permission to crawl or access the article full-text, metadata, and citations, and the use of an API for this purpose.

however, emailing them was fruitless. So I'm hoping someone scraped the data independently and made it available online.